# How can I debug POST requests with python's BaseHTTPServer / SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, http, command-line

I found a script on [this site](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) for running a simple server via the command line with python.

I added some `print` lines in because I'd like to print out the GET and POST parameters via the command line for requests, but I can't seem to get them to show up anywhere.

If I just print our  our the `s` variable (`pprint (vars(s))`) I end up seeing this:

```
{'client_address': ('127.0.0.1', 53373),
 'close_connection': 1,
 'command': 'GET',
 'connection': <socket._socketobject object at 0x10b6560c0>,
 'headers': <mimetools.Message instance at 0x10b689ab8>,
 'path': '/favicon.ico',
 'raw_requestline': 'GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\r\n',
 'request': <socket._socketobject object at 0x10b6560c0>,
 'request_version': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'requestline': 'GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1',
 'rfile': <socket._fileobject object at 0x10b6538d0>,
 'server': <BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer instance at 0x10b6893f8>,
 'wfile': <socket._fileobject object at 0x10b6536d0>}
```

I tried to then use the `print` command with each of the indices, (`pprint (vars(s.connection))`) but that's not working.

Here is the modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import BaseHTTPServer
from pprint import pprint

HOST_NAME = 'localhost' # !!!REMEMBER TO CHANGE THIS!!!
PORT_NUMBER = 9000 # Maybe set this to 9000.


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_HEAD(s):
                s.send_response(200)
                s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                s.end_headers()
        def do_GET(s):
                """Respond to a GET request."""
                s.send_response(200)
                s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                s.end_headers()
                s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
                s.wfile.write("<body><form action='.' method='POST'><input name='x' value='1' /><input type='submit' /></form><p>This is a test.</p>")
                # If someone went to "http://something.somewhere.net/foo/bar/",
                # then s.path equals "/foo/bar/".
                s.wfile.write("<p>GET: You accessed path: %s</p>" % s.path)
                s.wfile.write("</body></html>")
                pprint (vars(s))
        def do_POST(s):
                """Respond to a POST request."""
                s.send_response(200)
                s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                s.end_headers()
                s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
                s.wfile.write("<body><p>This is a test.</p>")
                s.wfile.write("<body><form action='.' method='POST'><input type='text' name='xxxxxxxxxxxx' value='0000000000000000000000' /><input type='submit' /></form><p>This is a test.</p>")
                # If someone went to "http://something.somewhere.net/foo/bar/",
                # then s.path equals "/foo/bar/".
                s.wfile.write("<p>POST: You accessed path: %s</p>" % s.path)
                s.wfile.write("</body></html>")
                pprint (vars(s))
                pprint (vars(s.connection))
                pprint (vars(s.headers))
                pprint (vars(s.request))
                pprint (vars(s.rfile))
                pprint (vars(s.server))
                pprint (vars(s.wfile))
                pprint (vars(s.fp))
                """pprint (vars(s.request))"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
        server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
        httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
        print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
        try:
                httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass
        httpd.server_close()
        print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

How can I print out POST and GET parameters using a simple script?

Desired output via the command line would look something like:

```
1.0.0.127. - - [03/Oct/2012 16:02:05] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
foo=1
bar=2
bis=3
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not tremendously obvious, but the handler is using sockets behind the scenes. So you need to read the raw data from the socket, and then interpret it.

Use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module.

- In Python 2, you want `urlparse.parse_qs`.
- In Python 3, the library is renamed: you want `urllib.parse.parse_qs`.

Import `urlparse`, and then modify your `do_POST` method like so:

```py
def do_POST(s):
        """Respond to a POST request."""

        # Extract and print the contents of the POST
        length = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = urlparse.parse_qs(s.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8'))
        for key, value in post_data.iteritems():
            print "%s=%s" % (key, value)

        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        ...
```

Set up a simple test client:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://localhost:9000'
post_dict = {'foo' : 1,
             'bar' : 2,
             'bis' : 3}

params = urllib.urlencode(post_dict)
post_req = urllib2.Request(url)
post_req.add_data(params)

response = urllib2.urlopen(post_req)
response_data = response.read()
response.close()
print response_data
```

Start the server, and then run the client:

```
ire@localhost$ python http_server.py 
Wed Oct  3 21:38:51 2012 Server Starts - localhost:9000
foo=[u'1']
bar=[u'2']
bis=[u'3']
```

Comment: This should have been `baz` not `bis` :)

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost - Just following the OP's example - take it up with him! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cgi` module instead of `urlparse`. `cgi` implements POST params parsing out of the box. Using well-tested libraries seems better.

`import cgi`

```
def do_POST(self):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={"REQUEST_METHOD": "POST"}
    )

    for item in form.list:
        print "%s=%s" % (item.name, item.value)
```